# Firebase Auth "Google Play Store is missing" issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have tried to connect  my app with firebase , But I cant 
Am using Android Studio 2.2.3

I have added dependencies  in 
build gradle( Project )

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and build gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private EditText editTextEmail,editTextPassword;
    private Button btnRegister;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        editTextEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    public void register(){
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+email+password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"fill all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering..");
        progressDialog.show();
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==btnRegister)
        {
            register();
        }

    }
}
```

the xml layout having 
two text fields (EditTexts) and 
One Button 
I got this code from a tutorial Video 
They executed this successfully  but i have tried  there is showing an exception

> 03-14 13:31:31.585 1054-1772/system_process V/WindowManager: Adding
>   window Window{f249820 u0 PopupWindow:5e4fee9} at 3 of 8 (after
>   Window{d1abaee u0
>   dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample.MainActivity})
>   03-14 13:31:31.642 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample
>   W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 03-14 13:31:31.642
>   2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to
>   set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe242b580, error=EGL_SUCCESS 03-14
>   13:32:00.808 1054-1225/system_process W/AudioTrack:
>   AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client 03-14 13:32:00.846
>   1054-1502/system_process V/WindowManager: not Base app: Adding window
>   Window{4bd695 u0
>   dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample.MainActivity}
>   at 3 of 8 03-14 13:32:00.852 2331-2619/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found. 03-14 13:32:00.852
>   2331-2619/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/GooglePlayServicesUtil:
>   Google Play Store is missing. 03-14 13:32:00.911
>   2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/EGL_emulation:
>   eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 03-14 13:32:00.912
>   2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to
>   set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe242b720, error=EGL_SUCCESS 03-14
>   13:32:01.335 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/EGL_emulation:
>   eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 03-14 13:32:01.335
>   2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to
>   set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe247da20, error=EGL_SUCCESS 03-14
>   13:32:01.721 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample V/RenderScript:
>   0xeed9da00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4

Comment: May I know whether the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 4):

The stacktrace says that the Google Play Store is missing in the device. For firebase to work, you need to have a device having Google Play Services 10 or higher. (From https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup ). If it is an Emulator, make sure you create the emulator with Google APIs included.